# k8s.Exceptions.KubeConfigException: kubeconfig file not found at /root/.kube/config

Tags: .net, kubernetes

I have a .net core project that calls the command var config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.BuildConfigFromConfigFile() but it throws an error saying  `kubeconfig file not found at /root/.kube/config`. Im using docker-desktop with kubernetes on my Windows 10 machine. Any ideas how to point it to the correct config path?

Comment: The default location for the config file is the current user's (home folder's) `.kube/config`. Your container is running as `root`, hence the location. You can change it by changing the container's user and|or setting the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable. You can also mount a config from the host into the container.

Comment: @FariyaRahmat yes your answered helped me figure out I was missing the config file. I had to copy the config file into my /app directory in the container since thats where it was looking for the my config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DazWilkin mentioned, The default location for the config file is the current user's (home folder's) `.kube/config`. Your container is running as `root`, hence the location.

The error message indicates that the Kubernetes configuration file **kubeconfig** is missing from the expected location **/root/.kube/config**. This file is crucial for establishing a connection to a Kubernetes cluster and performing various operations.

As per the official kubernetes documentation on [Organizing Cluster Access Using kubeconfig Files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/) :

> By default, `kubectl` looks for a file named `config` in the `$HOME/.kube` directory. You can specify other kubeconfig files by setting the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable or by setting the `--kubeconfig` flag.

For step-by-step instructions on how to create and specify kubeconfig files, see [Configure Access to Multiple Clusters for more information](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters).

**Note**: To choose the current context use **kubectl config use-context** command. Also ensure that you have the correct permissions to access the **kubeconfig** file.